# how to stop music background when play other music in flash cs3

Tags: flash, actionscript

how to stop music background when play other music in flash cs3 actionscript 2,I have music background also I have button(speaker) when I click the button ,the background music and button speaker play in same time,how to stop the background sound

Answer (score 0):

```
private function muteFunction(e:Event):void{
    if (isMuted==true) {
        sc = music.play();
        isMuted=false;
    }
    if (isMuted==false) {
        sc.stop();
        isMuted=true;
    }
}
```

Where sc is the SoundChannel object. An alternative is to set the volume to 0 so that it technically doesn't stop but just isn't audible.

Comment: Thanks to reply,but when I added your code to the action-script button (speaker),there are error "Attribute used outside class."